# awk to find non-matches in 2 files

Tags: awk

I am trying to find the lines in the below `file1` that are not found in `file2`.  The `awk` below runs but does not produce any results.  Thank you :).

**file1**

```
955763
957852
976270
```

**file2**

```
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75
chr1    957571  957852  chr1:957571-957852  AGRN-7|gc=61.2
chr1    970621  970740  chr1:970621-970740  AGRN-8|gc=57.1
```

**desired output**

```
2 ids found
976270 missing
```

**awk** (missing.awk)

```
BEGIN { FS="[[:space:]]+|-" }
NR == FNR { seen[$0]; next }
$3 in seen { found[$3]; delete seen[$6] }
END { print length(found) " ids found"
  for (i in seen) print i " missing" }

awk -f missing.awk file1 file2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

if file2 size is much bigger than file1, this approach is better

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}
     $3 in a{c++; delete a[$3]}
         END{if(c) print c " ids found"; 
             for(k in a) print k " missing"}' file1 file2

2 ids found
976270 missing
```

Comment: The `awk` runs great on the large file. Thank you :).